# Filter a 2d Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter

I have a simple 2d array containing x, y coordinates like this:

```
var c = [
        [1,10]
        [2,11]
        [3,12]
        [4,13]
        [5,15]
];
```

How can I extract only pairs that satisfy TWO conditions (one for x, one for y) and put those in its own array?
For instance:

```
for Each of c { 
  if (x > 3 && y > 13) {
   push.NewArray
   }
}
```

Newbie to JS here and can't find this on the web. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

With filter instead of push, like this:

```
const filtered = c.filter(([x, y]) => x > 3 && y > 13);
```

```js
var c = [
  [1, 10],
  [2, 11],
  [3, 12],
  [4, 13],
  [5, 15]
];
const filtered = c.filter(([x, y]) => x > 3 && y > 13);
console.log(filtered);
```

You need commas to separate array items too.

The destructuring there is equivalent to:

```
const filtered = c.filter((arr) => arr[0] > 3 && arr[1] > 13);
```

Comment: This is a very elegant answer.

Comment: Can you explain what the destructuring assignment is? the OP probably doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) which executes a predicate (aka handler) in order to extract the elements in the array who satisfies a specific condition, in your case `x > 3 && y > 13`.

You can use the function `filter` as follow:

```js
let c = [  [1, 10],  [2, 11],  [3, 12],  [4, 13],  [5, 15]],
    filtered = c.filter(function([x, y])/*This is the predicate (aka handler)*/ {
      return x > 3 && y > 13
    });
    
console.log(filtered);
```

In the code snippet above (`function([x, y]){}`), we used something called [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

**An approach using [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):**

```js
let c = [  [1, 10],  [2, 11],  [3, 12],  [4, 13],  [5, 15]],
    filtered = c.filter(([x, y]) => x > 3 && y > 13);
    
console.log(filtered);
```